# Kibana with Elastic Search, how to count the occurrence of a particular query?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

When I enter a query in Kibana, it displays the the occurrences of the query over a certain time period.

I would like to count exactly how many times the message occurs in a certain period of time. Is there an elastic search query that aggregates the message occurrences into a single, total count?

Answer (score 0):

If I am able to understand you correctly, you wish to view the occurence of a particular message over the past x interval.

Here's how you can do it then:

Create a metric visualization. Keep the aggregation as count. Add your message as the query filter in the filter bar.

Save the visualization

Add it to dashboard and set the time interval in dashboard to last X interval.